# Node https not resolving URL

Tags: node.js

I have a little issue I hope you can help me with.
We used to have a developer, who refactored some code and now it is not working.

```
const request = require('request'),
  API_KEY = '',
  https = require('https');

class ImageService {

    getActorImage(name) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${name}`, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          // todo: handle the error
          reject(error);
        }

        // todo: what if there are multiple results?
        var bodyAsObject = JSON.parse(body);
        var actor = bodyAsObject.results[0];

    https.get(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2${actor.profile_path}`, function (profileResponse) {
          var image_data = '';
          profileResponse.setEncoding('binary');

          profileResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
            image_data += chunk
          });

          profileResponse.on('end', function () {
            resolve(image_data)
          });
        });
      });
    });

    }


    getBackdropImage(backdropPath) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          https.get(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${backdropPath}`, function (backdropResponse) {
        var image_data = '';
        backdropResponse.setEncoding('binary');

        backdropResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
          image_data += chunk
        });

        backdropResponse.on('end', function () {
          resolve(image_data)
        });
      });
    });
    }

    getPosterImage(posterPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      https.get(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${posterPath}`, function (posterResponse) {
        var image_data = '';
        posterResponse.setEncoding('binary');

        posterResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
          image_data += chunk
        });

        posterResponse.on('end', function () {
          resolve(image_data);
        });
      });
    });
    }

    getPosterAndBackdropPath(imdbid) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      request.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/find/${imdbid}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&external_source=imdb_id`, (error, response, body) => {
        var responseAsObject = JSON.parse(body);
        var movie = responseAsObject.movie_results[0];
        var posterPath = movie.poster_path;
        var backdropPath = movie.backdrop_path;
        resolve({ poster_path: posterPath, backdrop_path: backdropPath });
      });
    });
    }

}

module.exports = new ImageService();
```

Now my problem is that even though there is data in actor.profile_path it does not resolve it to the actual path. and the same for everything else that uses the ${}.

If you could help me along here it would be very much appreciated

**UPDATE**

Have now tested this on windows, Mac and Ubuntu
it is only working on Mac

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Thomas

Comment: The `request` module transparently handles requesting from https. Do you know the reason for using the `https` module instead of using `request` throughout?

Comment: I have no idea why using https and not request. I tried with request but same issue.
I am a little lost here cause it was working like a charm before the refactoring, but then i am back to scratch with the whole thing.

Comment: Any idea as to what was refactored? Are you sure the refactoring was done in this module and not anywhere else? Did you try doing console.log of the URLs before calling https?

Comment: everything was refactored. I will try console logging it, didn't try that yet.

Answer (score 0):

The strings with `${}` need to be enclosed within **`** (*backtick sign*).

**For example:**

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${name}
```

should be changed to (*notice the backtick symbol at the start & end*):

```
`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${name}`
```

**Another example:**

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${posterPath}
```

should be changed to:

```
`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${posterPath}`
```

Comment: They do have the backtick at the start and the end. but still it is not getting the value from the ${posterpath} etc. i can see the value when debugging, but it is not resolving the url correctly